# Como agrandar el tamaño del area de un jscroll que dentro tiene un jtable

Tags: java

[image: captura de pantalla del jtable]Tengo en un proyecto Java un jtable que muestra los registros de una base de datos SQLite. Este jtable está dentro de un jscrollpane. El tema es que, cuando hay muchos registros, el área dentro del jscroll pane es muy pequeña y solo me alcanza a mostrar algunos registros ¿Alguien tiene alguna información que me ayude a resolver el problema?

Aquí les muestro: en esta tabla debería haber más de 1000 registros y sólo me muestra 56. Pero están los registros en el j table, solamente que el jscroll pane sólo muestra 56 rows de la tabla.

Comment: ¿Algún código y/o un *screenshot*?

Comment: Seguramente tendrás que añadir unas líneas de Java que, usando la cantidad de registros devueltos por la consulta SQL, redefina proporcionalmente el área del contenedor del scroll. Aunque sin ver el código sólo puedo especular...

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es agrandar el `JScrollPane` para que la tabla muestre más registros lo que tienes que hacer es esto..

```
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(ancho, alto));
```

Con eso debería funcionarte.